# Add class to table with element in GET url

Tags: jquery

I am getting some elements from another website and in order to match my current table structure and not have to add more css i need to an additional class to the tables found within each div.leaguehistorymodule i am grabbing. The existing table class is .homepagemodule and i want to add a .report class to them.

```
$.get(getHistoryUrl('game'), function (data) {
    $(data).find('.leaguehistorymodule').appendTo('#mfl-singlegame');
});
$.get(getHistoryUrl('season'), function (data) {
    $(data).find('.leaguehistorymodule ').appendTo('#mfl-singleseason');
});
$.get(getHistoryUrl('career'), function (data) {
    $(data).find('.leaguehistorymodule').appendTo('#mfl-career');
});
$.get(getHistoryUrl('playoffs'), function (data) {
    $(data).find('.leaguehistorymodule').appendTo('#mfl-postseason');
});
$.get(getHistoryUrl('milestone'), function (data) {
    $(data).find('.leaguehistorymodule').appendTo('#mfl-milestones');
});
```

Do i need to add the id for each call , or can you do one for all of them. I'm a bit lost on this.

I tired this

```
$(function() {
  $('.leaguehistorymodule').has('.homepagemodule').addClass('report');
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right you want to add the report class to all your homepagemodule objects. At the end of your code:

```
$('.leaguehistorymodule .homepagemodule').addClass('report');
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you might need to get the `HTML` of the element you're looking for, something like:

```
$(data).find('.leaguehistorymodule').html().appendTo('#mfl-singlegame');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(data).find('.leaguehistorymodule').appendTo('#mfl-postseason').addClass("report");
```